# Timertasks using cron expressions EJB3/JBoss 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cron, ejb-3.0, timertask

for my EE application, i have to consider clustered timertasks in JBoss 6 Environment. The tasks must be persisted in the database. While application initialization,the tasks must be created and scheduled from these persisted entites.

For example, i have an entity like this:

```
class MyTask {
   private Long id;
   private String cronExpression;
   private String name;
}
```

I can create new Jobs and CronTriggers using Quartz and using data sources, i can let them synced over cluster instances. But, what is the best strategy in JBoss Environment using EJBs?

Using Java EE facilities under "http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html" i could use @Schedule annotation with cron expressions. But my Job must be created dynamically from entity objects at runtime. How should my bean seem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TimerService](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) directly to programmatically create a timer rather than using @Schedule to automatically create one.

Comment: thanks for your answer. which strategy can i use on JBoss environment to cluster my timer service on whole farm?

Comment: The EJB spec requires that timers only fire once in a clustered environment, but I don't know the specifics for JBoss.  (Sorry, I didn't notice this was a JBoss-specific question.)